# "Выражать более выразительно" — допустимо ли так говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, тавтология, стилистическая-сочетаемость

"Свои мысли следует выражать более выразительно ", -
насколько допустима эта фраза?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такая фраза недопустима, это **тавтология** (повтор однокоренных слов).

Вариант редактирования: Свои мысли следует выражать **более ярко, красочно, живописно.**

Примечание.

Плеоназм от тавтологии отличается тем, что тавтология — это обычно употребление однокоренных (или сходных по звучанию) слов, а плеоназм — это лексическая избыточность, когда  происходит семантический повтор.

Comment: Очень хороший исчерпывающий ответ! Спасибо.